# Linq C# : Integer dbnull value how can I check it?

Tags: c#, linq, dbnull

I must convert into linq this query sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(tab1.IdUtente) AS NumClientiSenzaAccessi 
FROM tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.IdUtente = tab2.IdAttivazione 
WHERE (tab1.Demo = 0) AND (tab1.idRivenditore = 0) AND (tab1.IdGruppo <> 29) AND (tab1.IdGruppo <> 130) AND (tab1.IdGruppo <> 117) AND (tab2.IdAttivazione IS NULL)
```

I've tried to do this query:

```
var numClienti = (from u in contestoDB.tab1 
join c in contestoDB.tab2 on u.IdUtente equals c.IdAttivazione 
where u.Demo == demo && u.idRivenditore == 0 && u.IdGruppo != 29 && u.IdGruppo != 130 && u.IdGruppo != 117 && (c.IdAttivazione.ToString() == null) 
select u.IdUtente 
).Count();
```

But it always returns 0 and not other value!!! How can I compare with `DBNull` value of `c.IdAttivazione` and its type is nullable integer (`int?`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `into` on your join and then select from that and use the `DefaultIfEmpty()` so it can do a left join and keep all records from the left which did not join to the right.

```
var numClienti = (from u in contestoDB.tab1 
join c in contestoDB.tab2 on u.IdUtente equals c.IdAttivazione into uc
from ucc in uc.DefaultIfEmpty()
where u.Demo == demo && u.idRivenditore == 0 && u.IdGruppo != 29 && u.IdGruppo != 130 && u.IdGruppo != 117 && (ucc.IdAttivazione.ToString() == null) 
select u.IdUtente 
).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: (c.IdAttivazione.ToString() == null) => (ucc.IdAttivazione.ToString() == null)

Comment: @MikeVinyl Sorry I do not understand? Are you asking me a question?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to either directly compare to null if `IdAttiviazone` is a `Nullable<Int32>` or use the property `HasValue`.

```
&& c.IdAttivaZone == null
```

or

```
&& c.IdAttivaZone.HasValue
```

Depends on how well your linq to SQL query provider works.